# OpenCV mouse calls?

Tags: c++, opencv, mouse, mouseevent

I am using cvSetMouseCallback to track mouse clicks. However I need to pass in more than one argument to the function that is passed in to cvSetMouseCallback. However cvSetMouseCallback only accepts one parameter to pass in data to the function it calls. How I would I do this with more than one argument?

For example:

```
cvSetMouseCallback ("Window", function, argumentPassedintofunction);

void function (int event, int x, int y, int flags, void* param, CvRect *drawnRect,    IplImage *skinSegment, IplImage *colourSpaceImg, CvHistogram *skin, IplImage *planes [])

{

}
```

So as you see,  I need to pass in more than one parameter to function () but cvSetMouseCallback only allows one argument to be passed in.

I DO NOT WANT TO ACCESS THE OS FOR MOUSE CALLS (so not handles and any of that, I strictly want to stick to opencv)

Also making the arguments global variables isn't an option.

Comment: Can't you create a struct and pass that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make function take in a struct which contains all the parameters.

```
typedef struct func_params_ {
  int event;
  int x;
  int y;
  int flags;
  void* param;
  CvRect* drawnRect;
  ......
} func_params
```

Comment: perfect thanks :)
just one more thing - you know how classes are put in an separate file? is the same thing done with structures? or are they just put in main

What is done commonly? Sorry, I don't usually use structures